# What exactly is the meaning and usage of "communemque?"

Tags: conjunction

I'm reading through a Latin edition of the *Republic*. Book III starts off as follows:

> Haec igitur sunt, ut mihi videtur, quae de Diis audienda aut non audienda sint prima a pueritia his, qui Deos et parentes honoraturi sunt **communemque** amicitiam non parvi facturi.

I was drawn to what seems to be a conjunction, *communemque*, and searched through dictionaries, but never found a result. I found some sentences online that use it, but it just seems to be translated as "and," obscuring any contextual nuance.

What does this term mean, and how is it used?

Comment: It's not *communemque* that's translated as *and*, it's just the enclitic [*-que*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-que#Latin).

Comment: @Cairnarvon Can you write that as an answer? Being short doesn't invalidate the answer in any way; here the key insight happens to be just that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conjunction is not *communemque*, but just *-que*; it's an "enclitic" that attaches onto the previous word, like English *'s*. (It's generally written as part of the word, but that's a modern convention: the ancients abbreviated *senatus populus-que Romanus* as SPQR, with the *-que* separate.)

*Communem* here is an adjective modifying *amicitiam*:

> …qui Deos et parentes honoraturi sunt **communem-que amicitiam** non parvi facturi.
> *…who should honor the gods and their parents, **and** not take **their shared friendship** lightly.*

There are only a few enclitics in Latin; the others are *-ve* "or" and *-ne* "?" (marking a question).